Is this homebrew "Reinforce Spell" spell balanced?
One thing I've noticed when reading through the Player's Handbook is that spells with long casting times such as Hallow and Private Sanctum seem to be remarkably fragile, as a single one-action cast of Dispel Magic can clear as much as a year's work of daily spellweaving. Obviously, you'd want these spells to be more resilient than this, so I created this homebrew spell to fix this:

Reinforce Spell
4th level abjuration
Casting Time: 1 hour/level of spell being reinforced
Range: Touch
Components: V, S, M (A scrap of mithril)
Duration: Permanent
You reinforce a spell, making it more resistant to being dispelled.
Choose a spell within range that has a duration of 24 hours or longer that was cast with a spell slot lower than the slot this spell was cast with. Treat that spell as if it were cast at a level equal to (Spell's original level + (Reinforce Spell's level - Spell's original level) * 2) for the purpose of dispel magic and similar spells. For example, if you cast Reinforce Spell at 5th level on a 3rd-level spell, that spell would require a DC 17 check to be removed with dispel magic.

I have several questions about this spell:

Is this spell balanced, or does it facilitate exploits?
What is a good minimum cost for the material component? 100 gp/level? 500 gp/level? 1k gp/level?
Should I raise or lower the minimum level?
Do I need to add an "at higher levels" entry?


Are you a player or a DM?

Balance is not an issue here
Is this spell balanced?
I like this spells premise, although it is likely not a spell a PC would pick as a level pick, as what it aims to do is not that relevant for a PC caster that is adventuring. But as a flavor spell, if my wizard would find this in a spellbook or scroll while adventuring, he’d copy it to pimp our home base after we have settled down and the campaign is over. That is nothing that would influence the campaign itself, as it likely would only happen after the campaign ended - it's not a good idea to have no time pressure at all on the PCs, and so our DM would not give us a year of idleness to cast Private Sanctum over and over. So this more for in-world consistency, and the question of of balance does not really apply.
The other reason for the spell is of course as an in-game justification why the wards put up by an NPC wizard or cleric are hard to break. But, you are already the DM in that case. You can just set whatever DC you like on them, or declare they cannot be dispelled at all. There is no need for this spell in that case, just as there are no spells that explain in-game how all the permanent teleporters or other permanent magical effects that can be found all over in published modules were created.
Does it facilitate exploits?
This depends a bit what you consider an exploit, but I think the risk is low. You could make a permanent Arcane Lock or Major Image hard to get rid of, but I think in most circumstances that won't break anything. Moreover, this itself is a spell that can be dispelled, so unless you want to have turtles of reinforcement all the way down, if someone really wants to get rid of the protected spell, they can.
Should I raise or lower the minimum level?
Do I need to add an "at higher levels" entry?
This should be castable at higher levels. There are really only a handful of spells in the PHB that can be made permanent by repeat casting, and they include Teleportation Circle at 5th and Forbiddance and Guards and Wards at 6th, so unless you want this to not work for nearly half of those, make it so it can be upcast.
The level otherwise seems fine. Apart from maybe Illusory Script, Magic Mouth, Everburning Torch or Arcane Lock there is not that much to use it on at low levels, and this is anyways more something for off-stage downtime, where you have plenty of slots unused, so the level doesn't really matter that much. At higher levels you often burn your 5th level plus slots on scrying those days, so 4th seems like a fine place to stick this.
What is a good minimum cost for the material component?
Not all but nearly all spells that have a permanent effect do have some kind of costly component that is consumed, so this should have one too. Some of the other spells this reinforces are already pretty costly to make permanent in the first place (I am looking at you, Magic Circle), and wizards are notoriously tight on cash until they get close to fourth tier, so I wouldn’t overdo it for what amounts to being a mostly flavor spell. Maybe at most 100 gp/spell level.
Finally, I’d simplify the effect, to just have it add a flat +5 to the DC or such. The formula sounds pretty complicated, wouldn't even work at all on 9th level spells, and its not clear why it should be more difficult get rid of a low level reinforced spell than a higher level one.

I'll make a revised version soon.

This is very weak.
For starters, extremely few players will ever use this spell.  The casting time is prohibitively high for a use case that is already very rare.  Given how unlikely it is for enemies to even care about dispelling in the first place, it's a hard sell.
Even when it does come up, it provides too little protection.  Not only can it be circumvented by being dispelled itself, it isn't going to pose much of an obstacle to anyone dedicated to dispelling unless a very high level spell slot is used to reinforce a very low level spell.  Even then, it does nothing against Antimagic Field, a tool that many powerful spell-breaking enemies would rely on.
Suggested adjustment
Given the niche use, it would be entirely balanced for the spell to make the target spell entirely immune to dispelling - forcing the reinforcement to be dispelled first.  This would also remove the counterintuitive level formula from the mix, reducing the overall complexity.
It may also be a good idea to cause it to modify the appearance of the spell somehow.  That way, a player facing this spell would be able to know at a glance whether a Dispel Magic would be wasted.
